# I can't seem to change the save path

Tags: python

I keep getting this error message in my terminal:

```
C:\Users\Rockw\Desktop\Python>Watermarker.py
  File "C:\Users\Rockw\Desktop\Python\Watermarker.py", line 16
    saveLocation = "C:\Users\Rockw\Desktop\Python\Modified Photos" + fileName
                  ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I don't really know what this means or why it isn't working.

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes. They are being interpreted as the beginning of unicode sequences. `C:\\Users\\Rockw\\Desktop\\Python\\Modified Photos`

Comment: use raw prefix: `saveLocation = r"C:\Users\Rockw\Desktop\Python\Modified Photos"`...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre This worked!! Thank you so much!